# Android font awesome square instead of some characters (KitKat only)

Tags: java, android, rendering, font-awesome

I'm stuck with this issue, please look:
[image: Label on Android KitKat]

On newer Android versions label is correct:
[image: Label on Android Nougat]

My code to set font for TextView (view holder and list adapter), nothing special:

```
viewHolder.eventCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_category_text);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome.ttf");
            viewHolder.eventCategory.setTypeface(tf);
```

Fontawesome is embedded in assets. The only broken character is 'ż', other national characters are ok, icons are ok. Also, no problems with default system font.

Do  you have any ideas?

Comment: Is the upper case version of the glyph also broken? If not, you could use an ALL CAPS string for the title. Of course, this is just a workaround.

Comment: But I'm forced to not use all caps string, that label needs to be not uppercase

Comment: Then I would report the issue to the fontawesome development team.

Comment: More weird thing: similar Android app written using Xamarin Forms (C#) is able to render the same font correctly, even on KitKat.

Comment: Really weird...

Comment: Well, maybe I will end with 2 labels, fontwesome for icon only and regular defualt android font for remaining text.

Comment: That's reasonable.

Comment: In case you want to analyze some other iconic fonts: http://fontello.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with other font,may be it will be font issue.

Comment: Fontawesome is requirement for this project, unfortunately

Comment: is that possible to replace that character?

Comment: What do you mean? Not possible unless I want to make typo in labels

Comment: I think the answerer means if you can do like in German: `ä` can be rewritten `ae`, `ß` can be rewritten `ss`, ... and so on. Because old typewriters weren't made in Germany and didn't have these "special" characters.

Comment: Oh I see, not possible in this case